# How do I draw a text in openGL/java?

Tags: java, opengl, text, draw

I need to draw a String in Arial, lets say "hello world", on the  window (the game uses openGL). But I have no idea how to draw text using openGL. I have searched but have found nothing that I understand. So I basically need to draw a Arial string on the screen in openGL in java.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`TextRendrer`](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/docs/com/sun/opengl/util/j2d/TextRenderer.html) , Its in the first few links on a [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=jogl+drawing+a+string)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use slick if you're using lwjgl - http://slick.cokeandcode.com/ 
It's very easy to use, you simply create a unicode font, load the glyphs and then use it to write text.